# Objective-c - Use of undeclared identifier 'tableView'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to iPhone development and I am trying to use a table view, I have been following tutorials including Apples own.

I keep getting the following error

> Use of undeclared identifier 'tableView'

Please see the code below, your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return myObject.count;
    }
```

The entire .m file can be seen here http://ideone.com/K1yXQy and the .h file here http://ideone.com/0jYpUd

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unbalanced braces - the closing "}" is missing from  viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
        NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *thumbnail_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        NSString *author_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"author"];

    ...
    }
```

so the declaration for 
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return myObject.count;
    }

is seen as a continuation of the viewDidLoad method.

You also have an extra closing } at the end of 
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

so you need to add } to the end of viewDidLoad and remove the extra one from cellForRowAtIndexPath

If you look carefully you will see that the "-" at the start of the method declaration isn't at the left margin - this is your clue that you have } problems

Comment: Many thanks for your help, the viewDidLoad is closed just above - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning When I remove the closing brackets you stated it seems to be throwing up further errors

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the indentation, that will tell you where your problem lies in this case.  Note that tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: doesn't start in column 1, it starts indented by some number of spaces.  The previous method, viewDidLoad, isn't properly terminated, it's missing a trailing '}'

Comment: Add the }, select the whole file and enter ctrl-i to reformat everything should be good.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, the viewDidLoad is closed just above - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning When I remove the closing brackets you stated it seems to be throwing up further errors